# second license dedicated to one person

Tags: licensing

There is a project on github which is GPL-3 licensed. I want to use this code for my commercial project, but I don't want to open my codes. So, I contacted with the developer to check if she can change the license to BSD. She allowed me to use the code under BSD license. So what should be the next? Should developer upload another BSD license file to repo which dedicated to only me or whole process is not possible?

Comment: To be nitty, if she really allows you to use the code under BSD license, she cannot prevent you from distributing it further and make it available under BSD license to the world. So I guess she maybe wants to give you a modified BSD license, with the restriction of exclusive usage rights for you and/or this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developper of this project owns her code and provides it to the github users under GPL-3 license. Excellent! But she remains free to provide the code under other conditions to whomever she wants.

If she agreed with you, based on your arguments, that you may use the software under MIT, that's fine for your. But she's not obliged to grant the MIT terms to all the other github users.

Three points that you should be aware of:

- From a practical perspective (version management), I think that it would be a good idea to clarify if this right is granted to you for the current version only, or also the subsequent versions that will be published on github.
- The fact that she grants you right on her software, does not necessarily mean that you have any rights on the parts of the code written by other contributors.
- You should keep the email exchange, in which she confirms the MIT terms that she grants to you for this specific github project.  You may need at least this, as evidence, if later someone contests your right to use that software in close source.

If this is for business purpose, the best advise would certainly be to contact a lawyer or a qualified legal expert in your jurisdiction about such matters.  (*Here you'll find only software professionals, who, like me, only express their opinion based on similar experiences under the law of their own country, but which are not necessarily relevant nor accurate for your special case*)

Answer (score 0):

**If the authors of a library sent you a written permission, then you can use the code at conditions mentioned in that message.**

The permission message should:

- Have an author signature and statement, that the person issuing this message 
  has all copyrights needed - Open Source project ownership is usually shared 
  between all contributors, so you need a permission from each one of them.
- State clearly, that you're allowed to use a library in a commercial 
  project under BSD licensing.
- Include a copy of a license you're allowed to use (i.e BSD license).

You can find examples of such written permission online for reference. Don't forget to save and keep that message. And by the way, I'm not a lawyer, so if you have any doubts it's would be the best to consult one.

Comment: It would have to be a *license,* not just a note.